# jQuery event is not properly working in mobile (iOS, Android)

Tags: android, jquery, ios

jQuery event doesn't have any an issue at all in browser.

However, when in mobile browsers (iOS and Android), unless I click button 1, it doesn't properly recognizes the jQuery event. How can I fix it up for working  properly jQuery click event in mobile like in browser?

```js
$(function(){
     
      $(".btn2").css({"display":"none"});
      
      $("body").click(function(){ 
     if($("#menuSelect option:selected").index() > 0){
      $(".btn1").css({"display":"none"});
      $(".btn2").css({"display":"block"});     
     }
   })
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

   <section class="section">
     <select id="menuSelect">
      <option value="menu" selected="selected">choose one </option>
      <option value="a">a</option>
      <option value="b">b</option>
      <option value="c">c</option>
      <option value="d">d</option>
     </select>
    </section>
    
    <div>
          <p class="btn1 button"><input type="button"     value="button1" onclick="fn_popup_open('area_popup2');"/></p>
    <p class="btn2"><input type="button" value="button2" id="Apply"/></p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try it:

```
var myElement= document.getElementById('myelement');

myElement.addEventListener('click', function() {


alert('Hello world');

}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(function(){

      $(".btn2").css({"display":"none"});

      $("#menuSelect").change(function(){   
                    if($("#menuSelect option:selected").index() > 0){
                        $(".btn1").css({"display":"none"});
                        $(".btn2").css({"display":"block"});                    
                    } else {
          $(".btn1").css({"display":"block"});
                        $(".btn2").css({"display":"none"}); 
          }
            })
  });
```